# How do I programmatically serve css and js files to the browser using NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I like to server css and js files (or combine them to one minified) 
which are stored in a separate folder, which is not located in the public directory.

I have found this: 
[node.js sending css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304517/node-js-sending-css-files)

How can i render a express jade template including the dynamically added css / js files?

Comment: Generally, I'd say this would be better suited as a *build* step than an active feature of the application -- combine the "source" files into their "public" equivalents and serve the generated "public" files with [`static`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html). Tools such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), especially with its [collection of plugins](http://gruntjs.com/plugins), can help with the *building*.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is also interesting: https://github.com/piscis/piler-compat